# Can you define a function style macro for conditional compilation?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to define a macro called `IPHONE_ONLY` for conditional compilation that looks like this:

```
IPHONE_ONLY -(void)myMethod {
    //method body
}
```

or

```
IPHONE_ONLY( -(void)myMethod {
    //method body
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't surrounding the function with `#ifdef` work for you?

Comment: @Shahbaz It would but I'm working with a header file that has about a hundred method definitions and am looking for something that's easier on the eyes (my eyes at least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though normally you would surround the function with `#ifdef`, I tested with gcc and indeed the following also works. I don't know if it is standard:

```
#ifdef IPHONE
# define IPHONE_ONLY(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
# define IPHONE_ONLY(...)
#endif

IPHONE_ONLY(int func(void)
{
    return 12;
})
```

I have never seen anyone code like that though. It is quite common to write such a function like this:

```
#ifdef IPHONE
int func(void)
{
    return 12;
}
#endif
```

Your editor also would be much happier with this, since it understands functions, but not function body used as a macro parameter!

Comment: That might work, but it's ... questionable to introduce a comma like that.

Comment: @unwind, indeed, one parameter was enough for the macro. Although I'm not sure what you meant and what you had in mind of what could go wrong.

Comment: +1 For pointing out the possibility of passing the body of function as a macro parameter. Although it doesn't seem to be right thing to do.

Comment: @LihO, I agree. I just tested it out of curiosity (and to literally answer the question). I would absolutely not recommend it though.

Comment: As soon as you have a comma in your function, this will not work. E.g if you have an initialization `int x[] = { 1, 2 };`. You'd have to go with the solution in my answer to avoid that.

Comment: @JensGustedt, I had noticed your answer and you are absolutely right. I would fix this answer (especially since it's already marked as accepted)

Comment: @Shahbaz, sure, never mind, always improve answers if this is possible.

Comment: But now the `#endif` is missing :(

Comment: @JensGustedt, haha, I was too hasty I guess. I agree with you, I always try to improve the answers (even others').

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, but I don't think that this would make your code more readable

```
#if on_iphone
# define IPHONE_ONLY(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
# define IPHONE_ONLY(...) 
#endif
```

and then you can use the macro the 2nd way you have it in your question.

But this is really ugly and against the visual expectations of anybody who is used to read proper C.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`ifdef`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html):

```
#ifdef IPHONE_ONLY
void myMethod(){
    //method body
)
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifdef IPHONE_ONLY
# define MY_METHOD() myMethod();
 void myMethod() {

    ......

 }
#else
# define MY_METHOD()
#endif
```

in your c code of your project, you call `MY_METHOD()`.

This will avoid you to call `myMethod()` in that way each time you need it in your code

```
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        // some thing to do here
#ifdef IPHONE_ONLY
        myMethod();
#endif
        // other thing to do here
    }
```

with the definition above you will call your  `myMethod();` in this way

```
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        // some thing to do here
        MY_METHOD();
        // other thing to do here
    }
```

If `IPHONE_ONLY` is defined then the prepocessor will change the macro `MY_METHOD()` by the call of the function `myMethod();`

If `IPHONE_ONLY` is not defined then the preprocessor will change the `MY_METHOD()` by nothing. It's like the macro call `MY_METHOD()` does not exist in your code. and the function `void myMethod()` will not be defined